index.html file is not fully responding on cPanel
I have placed my index.html file under public_html folder but when I visit my website for example xyz.com the website does not load but when I visit with xyz.com/index.html it shows the page and website works.
But it is not working with my actual domain
What could be the issue?  I have also attached screenshot of directly where index.html file is present.


Can you let me know what you see when you visit just the domain (e.g. xyz.com)?

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.
